# Request to set Kubernetes tag default syntax highlighting to YAML

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

Please set the default language for [kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes) to `lang-yaml`.

Kubernetes configuration is mostly written in YAML and applied via [kubectl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubectl). While JSON is also possible to use, it's recommended to use YAML (see [best-practices doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#general-configuration-tips)).

Examples where defaulting the language would be helpful (recent new questions):

- [Unable to create ALBIngressConttroller in Kubernetes environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64784314/unable-to-create-albingressconttroller-in-kubernetes-environment)
- [Ingress controller name for the ingress class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64781320/ingress-controller-name-for-the-ingress-class)
- [Redirect from/to www with nginx-ingress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64777939/redirect-from-to-www-with-nginx-ingress)

Syntax highlighting request as per [highest-voted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/284048) on question [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: [Current Highlight.js maintainer here] Another great situation where it would be optimal if SE could set multiple languages per tag and then let us try to figure out whether it's JSON or YAML.  Also the suggestion here might be reasonable as well.

Comment: @JoshGoebel That's interesting to know. Pinging @Makyen who enabled it for the `kubernetes`-tag.